# How to create model without using Entity Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, orm, entity-relationship

I need to know how to implement the relationship in the model without using Entity Framework in C#.

[image]

Please give me a solution using this ER diagram.

```
class Student
        {
            public int studentId { get; set; }
            public string studentName { get; set; }
            public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
            public string street { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
            public string PIN { get; set; }
            public int courseId { get; set; }
            public string courseName { get; set; }
        }
    class Course
        {
            public int courseId { get; set; }
            public string courseName { get; set; }
        }

    class StudentHobby
        {
            public int studentId { get; set; }
            public string studentName { get; set; }
            public string hobby { get; set; }
        }
    class Lecturer
        {
            public int lecturerId { get; set; }
            public string lecturerName { get; set; }
            public int courseId { get; set; }
            public string courseName { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: **SHOW US** what **YOU** have tried so far! SO is **not** a free "write my code for me" service - **YOU** need to make an effort first, show us what you have and where you're stuck - **then** we'll help .....

Comment: I am entirely new to programming. I can code but the thing is I want to learn the best practice.

Comment: Well, then start by coding the four entities you show in the ER diagram as C# classes, and post them here - then we can go a step further and introduce the relationships

Comment: I dont know how to work with foreign key in model...Do i need to have separate properties or i can call the class...I have doubt on those

Comment: Good start - now for the FK: you should store *only* the FK column, e.g. `CourseId` - in the `Student` and `Lecturer` table. After all, this establishes the "link" to the `Course` table, and you can always load the corresponding `Course` to get the other details of the course (e.g. `CourseName`) - do **NOT** introduce unnecessary data duplication! Don't store `CourseName` in `Student` or `Lecturer` - **only** in the `Course` entity

Comment: Thanks. I can understand how to create the table with relationship. how abt the model structure? eg class Lecturer it should be like that or I have to do in this way
class Lecturer
        {
            public int lecturerId { get; set; }
            public string lecturerName { get; set; }
            public Course course { get; set;}
        }

Comment: Why are you specifically excluding Entity Framework here? That would make things **a lot easier**.....

Comment: I am new to programming. So i want to learn the basic structuring w/o using EF. I want to make sure whether i am following the bad practice in terms of model.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your entity classes should always contain

- their own "useful" data - e.g. attributes of that entity, like name and other information of the lecturer himself
- foreign key attributes to link to other entities, e.g. the `CourseId`, but nothing more

The basic principle of relational design is making sure you have your relationships in place, and you do eliminate all data duplication -> e.g. do **not** store the `CourseName` with the `Lecturer` class, since if you would, then if the course's name changes, you have to start updating that not only in the `Course` table, but also in all instances of the `Lecturer` and possibly `Student` rows that use that course. That's exactly what you're trying to avoid.

The idea is this: with the foreign key attribute `CourseId` stored on the `Lecturer`, if you load a lecturer, you can also take the FK attribute and then also load the corresponding `Course` and get all its details - without having to duplicate information across multiple tables / entities.

If you would consider using **Entity Framework**, you could **very easily** include those fk links as "navigation properties" on your classes:

```
public class Lecturer
{
     // Lecturer's own attributes
     public int lecturerId { get; set; }
     public string lecturerName { get; set; }

     // FK attribute
     public int courseId { get; set; }

     // FK navigation property
     public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

and then the "EF magic" would automagically do this "loading" in the background.

Now in your code, you could load a `Lecturer`, and by navigating on its `Course` navigation property, you can access all details of the `Course` as well - without duplicating any data.